# How can I modify a file stored in SharePoint via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, object-model

I have some files in SP 2010 that are simply HTML, and I need to modify the contents of those files in a systematic manner.

Is there a good way to do this using powershell?  Imagine that I want to find certain tags or text and replace them with something else, like replace "p" with "P".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's probably a bunch of different ways to do this, but here's a snippet from some C# code that I wrote a while back converted to PowerShell.  Hope it's along the lines of what you're looking for:

```
Start-SPAssignment -Global
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepointdev:90"
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("Site Pages")
foreach ($file in $list.RootFolder.Files) 
{
    if ($list.ForceCheckout) { $file.CheckOut() } 
    $html = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($file.OpenBinary())
    $html = $html.Replace("p", "P")
    $file.SaveBinary([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($html))
    if ($list.ForceCheckout) { $file.CheckIn() }
}
Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

Comment: TIL about the Start-SPAssignment -Global. Neat...

Comment: your replace statement would probably want to include "<p>","<P>" if you want to replace the tags.

Comment: The original question said "tags or text" and I just used his example for context.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great example, got me pointed where I needed to go.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're mentioning HTML files, you could also use the SPWeb.GetFileAsString() method to get the contents of the file and SPWeb.Files.Add(string, byte[], bool) to save the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this PowerShell function recently and thought it could be helpful for situations like the one you mention.  I haven't actually used it yet, but it could be another option for you.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/12/25/get-markuptag.aspx