# How do I edit the HTML source of a rich text column?

Tags: site-column, rich-text

I have a list with some text columns as Rich Text. I need to edit the HTML behind the scenes.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Go to the list and edit the item(s) in question. Or do you mean something different with like Powershell like described in [this post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17141/how-can-i-modify-a-file-stored-in-sharepoint-via-powershell)?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "behind the scenes"?

Comment: when I edit via Edit Properties - it gives me the editor; I;d like to change HTML of the content

Comment: no this is not giving me HTML since it's Rich Text col not Enhanced

Comment: So you mean something along the lines of the HTML editor or Source editor in a Content Editor web part?

Comment: Please **tag by feature** and not by version or product. This helps to attract more attention to your question and keep it relevant. See [How do I use tags](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

May be ribbon will solve your problem?

[image: instruction]

Comment: yes, sure - the trick was to change column text mode from Rich text to Enhanced. There is still no way to edit HTML of a Rich text column.