# How to edit HTML of a rich text field with an InfoPath edit form?

Tags: infopath, rich-text

When a list has it's edit form/s managed by InfoPath, all ability to edit the HTML of enhanced rich text fields is lost. The feature explained at [How do I edit the HTML source of a rich text column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17269/how-do-i-edit-the-html-source-of-a-rich-text-column) becomes no longer available.

Is there a way of gaining access to the HTML to edit it on an InfoPath managed form, without manually editing editifs.aspx or template.xsn?  (Say through a Greasemonkey script)

Is there a way of using a custom rich text editor control on an InfoPath HTML form?

Answer (score 1):

But Infopath Designer does not create HTML. Infopath Designer created forms are not even browser enabled by Sharepoint's InfoPath Forms Services by default.

If you want to develop HTML, use other development tools like Sharepoint Designer.

**Update:**
It might be useful to undersand Sharepoint architecture. Most "HTML" are produced dynamically from templates by XSLT rules and the data as well as rules are stored in content database as XML. Only!

While one can override it with its own home-grown code and all internet is filled by it. But it is really from lack of Sharepoint understanding and skills to do it in a Sharepoint way.

**Update2:**

> Is there a way of gaining access to the HTML to edit it on an InfoPath
>   managed form, without manually editing editifs.aspx or template.xsn?
>   (Say through a Greasemonkey script)

Again, there is no Infopath **HTML** form, Infopath forms are XML based.
There is no ready HTML (but just XML data for generating HTML by sharepoint on the fly, dynamically)...

Form template (in case of Infopath .XSN file template) doesn't contain any data (except default values for fields/columns). It is used to fill data to generate on the fly XHTML/HTML/ASPX pulling data from:

- in case of sharepoint lists from sharepoint list item
- in case of sharepoint libraries from .XML files stored in libraries

**In case of a sharepoint library**

For example, for a filled Infopath form with filled Rich Text Box control the corresponding

[image]

the corresponding XML file (containing href to template.xsn path) stored in sharepoint library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.5" productVersion="14.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="https://gennadyvanin.sharepoint.com/Web1/FormLibRichText/Forms/template.xsn"   name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:FormLibRichText:-myXSD-2012-08-18T09-54-41" ?>  
  <?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?>    
      <my:myFields xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-08-18T09:54:41" xml:lang="ru">  
  <my:field1>
         <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Testing
         </div>    
         <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                 <font color="#ff0000">Red color
                 </font>
         </div>   
         <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
             <strong>Bold</strong>
         </div>  
         <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
         <em>Italic</em>
         </div>  
         <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
               <font size="6">Font Size 24
               </font>
         </div>
```

The location of XML file depends but it is not difficult to find it, parse its content and saving back.

The access to this Infopath form data .XML file in case of sharepoint libraries, is transparent, And you can parse the correspmding XM data  from sharepoint side or in Infaopth code.

**In case of a sharepoint list**

**editifs.aspx** of the question  is used for editing a list item using linked to it created OOTB Infoapth **Sharepoint List Form** web part linked to Infopath template and data is pulled from a sharepoint list at run-time depending on chosen list item

The Infopath .XSN file template is again used for generating final code of the editing ASPX page to fill/edit data directly into/from a list.

Infopath does not avail custom coding for **Sharepoint List Form**s. Its schema and main data source are locked. **Infopath Designer 2010** does not avail **Developer** tab for such kind of forms permitting access to VSTA (Visual Studio Tools for Applications) custom coding in other types of Infopath forms

[image]

and it is explicitly said so in documentation on Infopath. See, for example,, Table 3. Comparing Infopath 2010 form library and list templates  in msdn article [Building SharePoint Applications with InfoPath 2010 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff961896.aspx#IP14BuildingSPApplicationsPT1_SPAppArchitecture)

[image: Table 3. Comparing Infopath 2010 form library and list templates]

The point is that in case of Infopath, and I believe it is the same in sharepoint model/architecture, the HTML/ASPX is generated dynamically (aka on the fly aka at run-time) from a form template and stored separately from it data.

Comment: Infopath Designer can produce two types of form, one is as you describe, the other is HTML.

The HTML in question however refers not to that which makes up a form, but rather the HTML stored in a SharePoint rich text field by fields bound to these on Infopath forms. This HTML is written by an Infopath form GUI, with no option to edit the code directly.

Comment: Don't you confuse HTML with XML? You may look to "code" of Infopath form by File --> Publish --> Export Source Files. The produced files are all XML and you can check wjat you can edit. Anyway, Infopath Designer is the best WYSIWG editor of XML

Comment: I accept that the bulk of the web form layout information is stored in an XML file. However, this is not the data in question. I am refering to the information stored in SharePoint lists in rich text fields. This information is stored as HTML.